# Name error using user input on python class attribute

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm building a very simple text based RPG for new starters in my office. Currently, I'm trying to use user input to create an instance of a class. Defining the player using their own input.

This is my current code:

```
# DEFINE CLASSES #
class Character:
    def __init__(self, name, dept):
        self.name=name
        self.dept=dept
class Player(Character):
    def __init__(self, name, dept, level):
        super().__init__(name, dept)
        self.level = level
class Item:
    def __init__(self, name, position, unlocked):
        self.name=name
        self.position = position
        self.unlocked = unlocked
# USER INPUT # 
User = Player(str(input("What is your name?")),str(input("What dept do you work for?")),1)
```

The goal is that an instance of the class 'Player' is created with user inputs for the attributes name and dept.

However running the code currently gives a NameError: name '(whatever the input is)' is not defined

I'm sure it's something really basic, since I'm new to python. Any help is very welcome!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

<s>From [Python documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#input) :</s>

> input([prompt]) -> value
>
> Equivalent to eval(raw_input(prompt)).

If you don't want the inputed text to be evaluated, use `raw_input()` instead.

As suggested in comments this is only for Python2, but your error indicates that's the Python version you are using.

I suggest you add the following shebang to your file : `#!/usr/bin/env python3`

Then start your program with `./mypythongame.py` after you've allowed execution of the script

Moreover, your `Character` class have to inherit from `object` in order to be callable with `super(Character, self).__init__()` or (in Python3) : `super().__init__()`

Comment: Note that the question is tagged `python-3.x`, which indicates that the asker at least *intended* to write it in Python 3. `raw_input()` isn't valid in Python 3.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, could you explain what you mean in your last sentence?

(I'm writing in Python 3, btw. I was just being very silly an executing in Python2)

Comment: @Neb this is still only valid for Python2 actually

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are running the script using python 2. I was able to run the scripts without error in python 3. Please run the script with python 3.

```
python3 your-script.py
```

In python 2 you would use the `raw_input()` built-in function to get user input as a string. The `raw_input()` function takes user input and converts it to string (stated [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html)).
Calling the python 2 built-in [`input()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#input) function is the same as calling [`eval()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#eval) on the output of the `raw_input()` function. Thus these two calls are the same:

```
a = input("Enter a number: ")  
b = eval(raw_input("Enter a number: ")
```

In python 3 the `raw_input()` built-in function does not exist. To get user input you can use the `input()` built-in function. `input()` in python 3 is equivalent to `raw_input()` in python 2.

Comment: An explanation of *why* would be useful.

Comment: Thanks. I was writing in Python3, but was executing in Python2. Glad to know I'm not going mad!